# Regex not working on Python 2.6.6

Tags: regex, python-2.6

Hello i have a regex problem,

This is the text structure:

> TK00123456: Change a lot gibberish 16:34. ---  access : [ more
>   gibberish  Module](http://somewebsite.com/selectedModuleCode=Support
>   form.aspx longblob)  summary --- | Properties | | --- Creator | more
>   gibberish | 16/01/2018 16:26:53 Manager | External Status |
>
> Working on Resolution
>   Proper English Text

This is my regex

```
re.match(r'(?s)Change(.*?)Working', text)
```

Output:

`None`

Using same RegEx on https://regex101.com/

```
Match 1 Full match  12-270
```

> `Change a lot gibberish 16:34. ---  access :
>   [ more gibberish 
>   Module](http://somewebsite.com/selectedModuleCode=Support form.aspx
>   longblob)  summary --- | Properties | | --- Creator | more gibberish |
>   16/01/2018 16:26:53 Manager | External Status |
>
> Working`

I have python version 2.6.6 on RHEL and I cant upgrade to python 2.7 if that is the problem.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `re.search()` rather than `re.match()`:

```
import re

string = """


    TK00123456: Change a lot gibberish 16:34. --- access : [ more gibberish Module](http://somewebsite.com/selectedModuleCode=Support form.aspx longblob) summary --- | Properties | | --- Creator | more gibberish | 16/01/2018 16:26:53 Manager | External Status |

    Working on Resolution
    Proper English Text
"""

rx = re.compile(r'(?s)Change(.*?)Working')
print(rx.search(string).group(0))
```

---

**Explanation**: `re.match()` only matches at the beginning of the string and there is no `Change` (see the `TK00123456:` there?).

Comment: Thank you with search the problem is gone :)